# Plotting two returned Lists in one curve

Tags: python, matplotlib

this code plots both list items as y in separate lines. I would like to plot these two lists in one line(or curve), as f(a_list)=(b_list). Any suggestions

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show
def p(a,b):
    a_list = []
    b_list = []
    while a < 10:
        a_list.append(a)
        b_list.append(b)
        a = a+1
        b = b+1
    return a_list, b_list
print(p(1,1))

plot(p(1,1))

show()
```

Comment: What package is `plot` from?

Comment: its from matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: Try replacing `plot(p(1,1))` with `plot(*p(1,1))`.

Comment: i tried it and i had this error: "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'function' "

Comment: @aflatoon Are you sure you ran `plot(*p(1,1))`? That error doesn't match it.

Comment: I'm sorry! I'm new with python, I did (p*) and not (* p), now it works thank you very much. can u maybe explain what did this (*) did?

Comment: @Enzo Could you post that as an answer please? OP wrote above that it solved the problem :)

Comment: @wjandrea Oh ok, I've added an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The `matplotlib.pyplot.plot` receives two arguments: `x` and `y`.

If `x` is a sequence of lists, it'll plot each list as a different curve. Since your `p` function returns a sequence of lists and you're passing a single argument to `plot`, so it'll plot two different curves.

You can fix it by two ways:

- Using [multiple assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), you can set each list returned by `p` to two different variables and pass these variables to the `plot` function:

```py
x, y = p(1, 1)
plot(x, y)
```

- Using [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments), you can set each list returned by `p` to its respective parameter in `plot`:

```py
plot(*p(1, 1))
```